# Shorthand for jQuery ($) breaking scripts. Must use long version

Tags: jquery

I recently took over some code from someone and I am running into a problem (more of an annoyance) that I've never had before. It's also proving difficult to research.

Basically this person used jQuery to select controls and not the shorthand `$` version. For example

```
jQuery("#controlid").val();
```

is used in stead of

```
$("#controlid").val();
```

The latter breaks any jQuery script that I create using the `$` shorthand.

Has anyone experienced something like this before? Is there maybe something small that I need to change for this annoyance to go away?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of error message do you get when the script is 'breaking' if it is $ is not defined you could assign jQuery to it: $ = jQuery

Comment: Wouldn't `var $ = jQuery` solve your problem?

Comment: place this in your code $.noConflict();

Comment: @MoYapro the error I am getting is

[10:13:28.797] TypeError: $ is not a function @ http://localhost:14536/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

Comment: @xaoonipu var $ = jQuery works, but I don't understand why. I mean I have been using jquery for years now and I feel it's a hack to add something like that to the code. I've never had to before.

Comment: @MrThursday: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj I added $.noConflict(); to the top of the script, but just get [10:16:45.651] TypeError: $ is undefined @ http://localhost:14536/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1**: [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them.

```
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here, not jQuery
```

**Solution #2**: `$` Alias

```
// Option #1, Document Ready Event
jQuery(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});

// Option #2, Anonymous Invocation
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The reason is definitely because a script is loaded after jQuery that utilizes the `$` as an alias for itself, which results in it no longer belonging to jQuery.

Comment: OK so basically I need to find the offending script and see why it's assuming control of $ and try and work around it. I think it could be considered a bit of a hack to put `var $ = jQuery` or `$.noConflict();` on top of every new script that I create.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to comment `$.noConflict();` out on top of one of the scripts the person I took the code over from wrote before. Thanks for helping, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: That's what we're here for. :)